# How to gain utility powers from multiple other classes

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, multi-classing

What are the options for a character that wants to gain utility powers from more than one class other than their own?

I am aware of the following options so far:

- Paragon Multiclassing
- The [Resourceful Magician](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=456) PP, whose 16th level feature enables the character to choose powers from any arcane class for which they have a multiclass feat.

However, both of these require a specific paragon path (and in the latter case, being a bard).  My concrete case is that I have a Bard/Summer Rhymer, MCed into Warlock and Wizard.  He has taken the [Acolyte Power](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=340) feat in order to pick up [Ethereal Sidestep](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7404), and I definitely don't want to give that up.  However, I would really like to have the Wizard utility power [Arcane Insight](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=4236) on-hand too.  Is there any way I can have my character acquire this second utility power from a multiclass?

I should mention that my character is a Half-Elf as well, in case there's some Dilletante-like ability that applies to low-level utility powers.

(I'm aware that a wand could be created with this spell as a Daily power - I think it would be a level 7 item?  That's a reasonable fall-back though not as good as picking up the power innately.)

Comment: Thanks for the links of the powers, made answering much faster and easier.

Comment: If there's something specific you're trying to do with all these utility powers, it might be better to simply ask how you can do that thing, within the constraints you have placed on you (e.g. if you already have a character build you can't change). There may be a better way than obtaining a bunch of classes' utility powers.

Comment: @Johathan - Good point.  My real goal in this situation is to get rerolls (preferably per-encounter) to Arcana checks.  Having said that, I would be interested in whether there are ways to do this *in general*, in case I come across other situations in future.  Especially as a half-elf bard should be king of using other class' powers!

Comment: @Andrzej I suggest you open a question asking how to get a number of Arcana rerolls per encounter then!

Comment: Why not just play a classless game?

Answer (score 1):

**There is a better way to achieve lots of teleports**, this way you can retrain your Acolyte Power for Arcane Insight:

1. Take the feat Bardic Wayfarer, when you teleport an ally with a power, you can also teleport 1 square.
2. Take the feat Walk Among the Fey, now you can teleport creatures when you would slide them.
3. Take lots of sliding powers. Your Majestic Word is such a power.
4. Buy items like Mithrendain Steel Weapon and Eladrin Armor to increase teleport distances.

You give allies teleport with Walk Among the Fey, and this in turn gives you teleport with Bardic Wayfarer. So you *do not need* an additional way to teleport.

See this [WotC community post](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3022036) for further ideas.

Comment: Thanks - though I've already taken [Bardic Wayfarer](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2972), and have several teleportation items.  Majestic Word already grants a teleport as part of Bardic Wayfarer, so no need for Walk Among The Fey to do that.  The missing part in your solution is an at-will teleport for myself, which Ethereal Sidestep does.  Losing that would make a significant difference in how my character plays (I basically never walk anywhere any more).

Comment: Plus in terms of taking [Walk Among The Fey](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2974) for giving allies mobility, I'm nearly epic and so will soon have the U22 [Queen's Clemency](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12518) to teleport adjacent allies as an at-will minor.  (Which, with Bardic Wayfarer, lets me teleport too).

Comment: You are right, you can not use my combination as a replacement for walking.

Answer (score 1):

One option that I've just come across for this specific situation, is to remove my requirement on having a *power* to teleport at-will.

The Epic-level feat [Fey Shift](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3655) would apply to my half-elf, and also grants at-will teleportation.  This is *slightly* worse than Ethereal Sidestep overall in that it's not a power, so its range cannot be boosted with an [Incisive Dagger](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1616).  But it does benefit from most other teleport enhancers, and it may well be worth taking this feat in order to free up Acolyte Power for the wizard U2.

Answer (score 1):

Also, another equipment based option for teleporting is the *Staff of the Traveler* (*PHB3* pg.212)

> **Critical:** You teleport the target 2 squares per plus
>   **Property:** Whenever you shift, you can instead teleport the 
>   number of squares you would have shifted.
>   **Power (Encounter ♦ Teleportation):** Free Action.
>   Trigger: You teleport using a psionic teleportation power.
>   Effect: You teleport the same number of squares that you 
>   teleported using the triggering power.